# Extract specific data entries(as groups) from a list and store in separate lists?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

For example, here is a sample of the list i am looping over, 
['n', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n',  'n', 'n', 'n', 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', ''n', 'n', 'n', 178, 179, 180]

This list is generated from a previously called function(the n's have been inserted to hide unwanted values).

I am attempting to group the numbers which are separated between n's and send them to a list, for instance take the numbers 1-37->put in a list, take numbers 82-88->different list, 178-180->send to different list.

The tricky part is that the list will not always have the same set of data inside, the 'groups' can be of arbitrary size and location. The only defining feature is that they are separated by n's.

My attempt so far:

```
for i in range(0, len(lists)):
        for index, item in enumerate(lines):
            if item != 'n': #if item is not n send to list
                lists[i].append(item)           
            elif lines[index+1] == 'n':#if the next item is an n
                 del lines[:index]
```

Where 'lists' is actually a list of lists created outside this function, to store each of the groups, the number of lists is determined by the number of groups that is needed to be stored.

'lines' is the list of values I wish to loop over.

My logic is, all values that is not an 'n' append in the first list, if the next value is an n, then delete all values before and loop over the new list putting the next set of values into the next list. so on.

except I get: list index out of range

Which I understand, but I was hoping there was a way to hack around it. I have also tried breaking out of the loop at the elif, but then I cannot continue the loop where I left off. 
My final attempt was to restart the loop at a location set after the first run like so:

```
place=0
    for i in range(0, len(lists)):
        for index, item in enumerate(lines[place:]):
            if item != 'n': #if item is not n send to list
                lists[i].append(item)           
            elif lines[index+1] == 'n':#if the next item is an n
                 place=[index]
                 break
```

slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Hope that was clear, Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> data = ['n', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 178, 179, 180]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x != 'n') if k]                                                                                                
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37],
 [82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88],
 [178, 179, 180]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby

data =  ['n', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 178, 179, 180]

def keyfunc(n):
  return n == 'n'

groups = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc) if not k]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
li=['n', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 178, 179, 180]

from itertools import groupby

def is_n(c): return c=='n'

print [list(t1) for t0,t1 in groupby(li, is_n) if t0==False]
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37], [82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88], [178, 179, 180]]
```

If you want to do this 'raw' (without itertools) this works:

```
def is_n(c): return c=='n'

def divide(li, f):
    r=[]
    while li:
        while li and f(li[0]):
            li.pop(0)
        sub=[]
        while li and not f(li[0]):
            sub.append(li.pop(0))
        r.append(sub)
    return r

print divide(li,is_n)
```

Or, if you want to use a for loop:

```
def divide4(li,f):
    r=[]
    sub=[]
    for e in li:
        if f(e):
            if len(sub)==0:
                 continue
            else:
                r.append(sub)
                sub=[]    
        else:
            sub.append(e)
    else:
        if len(sub): r.append(sub)
    return r  

print divide4(li,is_n)
```

Either case, prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37], [82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88], [178, 179, 180]]
```

itertools is faster, easier, proven. Use that.